# Create DXF file with ogr2ogr, that is visualized in AutoCAD

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, ogr, autocad

with ogr2ogr I try to create a DXF file, that is labeled and visualized in AutoCAD directly.

1. What I did to visualize point objects:

`ogr2ogr --config GDAL_DATA "X:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal" -f "DXF" X:\OSGeo4W64\new_file11.dxf OCI:secret1/secret2@("DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =secret_host )(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =secret3))):WW_MANHOLE" -nlt POINT -a_srs EPSG:25832 -clipsrc 408148 5794500 408400 5794700 -mapFieldType Integer64=String`

With that, the gdal-standard header.dxf and trailer.dxf are used.
If I open "new_file11.dxf" in AutoCAD Map 3D I first have to use the commands
PDMODE und PDSIZE to see the point-objects.

I wonder: How do I have to change the standard header.dxf-File of OGR/Gdal, that I can see DIRECTLY Point-data visualized in Autocad Map 3D?
(without manual PDMODE und PDSIZE-commands)?

From different survey offices I get data and, if I open these data, in AutoCAD I can see immediately the objects and labels.
That is what I trey to realize with ogr2ogr.

2. What I did to visualize attributes/labels:

`ogr2ogr --config GDAL_DATA "X:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal" -sql "SELECT geom,'LABEL(f:Arial,t:'||FID||')' AS OGR_STYLE from ww_manhole" -f "DXF" X:\OSGeo4W64\new_file14.dxf OCI:geheim1/geheim2@("DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host )(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =geheim3))):WW_MANHOLE" -nlt POINT -a_srs EPSG:25832 -clipsrc 408148 5794500 408400 5794700 -mapFieldType Integer64=String`

I want to visualized the data-attribute "FID" of my data.
If I open that file (new_file14.dxf) in AutoCAD and zoom to the objects, I can see the labels, what is quite good. :-)
But I cant see any point objetcs, I just see the text?
Even if I try with the AutoCAD-commands PDMODE und PDSIZE, I can`t see the points?
Has anyone an idea why is that?

What I try to realize:

I want to create point-data with ogr2ogr, that are visualized directly in AutoCAD (without PDMODE und PDSIZE-commands)
AND are labeled with their attributes.
Has anyone an idea how to solve that?

I use gdal/ogr on Windows in version 2.4.0 with OCI library to work with Oracle data